# Creating a company ID column based on email address in R (dplyr answer preferred)

Tags: r, methods, statistics

I haven't tackled this part yet, but I figured I'd throw it up here to see if I can get some hints before I attempt this tomorrow. I have a list of emails with varying addresses: john@ketchup.com, cindy@mustard.com, bob@relish.com. I'd like to create a column that assigns each new company name an ID. For example, if @ketchup, company ID=1, if @mustard.com, company ID=2 and so on and so forth.

Would I be able to use dplyrs mutate function for this? I'm thinking the "starts with" command on the emails and create a new column based on the emails? -- The only downside that I can think of to this solution is that if the email list was larger (thankfully mine can be done manually), you'd have to assign an ID per email which may become cumbersome..

Anyways, answers are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could extract the substring after the `@` and use `match` to create a new column of 'ID's

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    separate(email, into = c('prefix', 'suffix'), sep= "@", remove = FALSE) %>%
    mutate(ID = match(suffix, unique(suffix)) %>%
    select(-prefix, -suffix)
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! I understand the code up until the mutate(ID=match(suffix, unique(suffix)). So this command is specifying to create a new  variable called "ID" and to compare each suffix to a unique suffix? When I run this command, I don't get a separate column that populates.  

Then the selec (-prefix, -suffix) is just to remove those from the dataframe, correct?

Thanks for clarification!

Comment: @D500  The `prefix/suffix` columns are splitted at '@', then the `ID is created based on `suffix` and removed those columns.  Another option would be to just get the `sufix` part with `str_extract` i.e `mutate(suffix = str_extract(email, `(?<=@).*$'))` and then do the `match`

Comment: library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    separate(email, into = c('prefix', 'suffix'), sep= "@", remove = FALSE) %>%
    mutate(ID = match(suffix, unique(suffix)) %>%
    select(-prefix, -suffix)

At the moment, the original code only produces IDs= 1 on all email suffixes. Isn't it supposed to create a new ID per unique suffix it matches? For example: g@companyx = 1, g@company = 2, g@companyz= 3? 

Does the code work for you?

Comment: @D500  Do you have string like `"g@companyx = 1`  I was under the assumption that the string is `g@compnayx"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @akrun for the initial answer, but I was unable to run it as posted. I modified it a bit and now it works-- it now assigns a unique ID to each unique suffix match and assigns incremental numbers:

> library(dplyr) library(tidyr) df1 %>%
>       separate(email, into = c('prefix', 'suffix'), sep= "@", remove = FALSE) %>%
>       mutate(ID = match(suffix, unique(suffix)) %>%
>       select(-prefix, -suffix)